# "Access Denied: Table X: Permission bigquery.tables.updateData denied on table X (or it may not exist)."

Tags: google-bigquery, http-archive

I am using this Bigquery code below:

```
MERGE `httparchive.sample_data_2020.response_bodies_desktop_10k` target

USING `webhistory.domlist.domains` source

ON target.NET.reg_domain(page) = source.host

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

I get the following error message:

> "Access Denied: Table httparchive:sample_data_2020.response_bodies_desktop_10k: Permission bigquery.tables.updateData denied on table httparchive:sample_data_2020.response_bodies_desktop_10k (or it may not exist)."

How can I solve this?
Thank you!

----Update
When I try this, I get the error below...

```
MERGE `webhistory.domlist.domains` target
USING `httparchive.sample_data_2020.response_bodies_desktop_10k`  source
ON target.host=source.NET.reg_domain(page)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

Access Denied: Table httparchive:httparchive_desktop2020sample.response_bodies_desktop_10k: User does not have permission to query table httparchive:httparchive_desktop2020sample.response_bodies_desktop_10k.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you have Bigquery.read role?
See if you have this role in IAM
roles/bigquery.dataEditor